# Acceptability of the phrase "While yet others" in formal English

Tags: grammaticality, formality, sentence-starts

Is it acceptable to use the phrase "While yet others" at the start of a sentence in formal English? Are there any alternative phrases that I could use?

To put this into context, I wish to write something along the lines of:

> In certain countries, the debate surrounding austerity versus growth [...]. In others, [...]. **While yet others**, have decided upon [...].

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's fine; but you don't want a comma after it, since in this case "others" is the subject of the sentence which follows. If you want to maintain strict parallelism, you would write "In yet others, it has been decided ... " or something of the sort.

Comment: As a side note, an ellipsis consists of three periods. Not four, not two, not five. Exactly three. Always. Whence the colloquial name "dot-dot-dot".

Comment: @StoneyB thanks. I'd take that as an answer. RegDwighт I always thought an ellipsis that encompassed the full stop at the end of the sentence made it 4 dots (3 + 1): am I wrong?

Comment: There's differences of opinion, but it's common for style guides to require the four dots as you say (an elipsis followed by a period, for four dots total), particularly if noting the end of the sentence is important as it's followed by the beginning of another, as in your question. With the last it doesn't matter that the sentence ends somewhere (of course it does).

Comment: What @JonHanna says. Also relevant: 1)When you follow the admirable MLA usage of bracketing your ellipses, the fourth dot is left to fall in its natural place as a period component of the passage quoted. If the ellipsis crosses a sentence boundary, it's simply absent. 2)In this particular case, however, since what you're "quoting" is not a published text but a projected one, the dotsets represent not ellipses but suspensions; they should be set down without brackets, and without the periodic dot.

Comment: What really was the objection to the phrase *while yet others*? In what way is it likely to be objectionably different? In short, what made you ask this question? So we could know, than speculate.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22While+yet+others%22 About **2,400,000** results

Comment: @Kris I'm guessing that OP worried that "while" might only be usable as a preposition or as a subordinating conjunction, not as a coordinating conjunction, especially at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“While yet others” is perfectly fine. Employing *while* as a coordinating rather than subordinating conjunction is a natural and widespread extension to which only the most reactionary of pedants would take exception. But in your construction it should not be followed by a comma, because “others” here is the subject of the sentence which follows:

> While yet others have decided ...

If you want to maintain strict parallelism, you should start your third sentence with an “In” phrase as well:

> In certain countries, the debate ...
>   In others, ...
>   In yet others, it has been decided to ... (*or something similar*)

But this is a rhetorical nicety which is not obligatory, and in fact will not even be noticed unless your sentences are fairly short. If your sentences are long, or if more than a sentence intervenes, you would do better to mark your periods with a repetition of “countries” as well, to make sure your readers keep their bearings:

> In certain countries, the debate ...
>   In other countries, ...
>   In yet other countries, it has been decided to ...